# Creation of a vector wrapper from an object which only allows accessing vector with index

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I created a class for using chainable Filter and Map operations mostly for avoiding redundant for loops.

For example

```
std::vector<ObjectASharedPtr> temp = GetListOfA();
FunctionalIteratableWrapper<ObjectASharedPtr> wrapper( temp );
wrapper.Filter([]( ObjectASharedPtr objA ){ return objA->isApple(); } ).Map([]( ObjectASharedPtr objA ){ return objA->Bite(); })
```

Short version of my class can be seen in the bottom of the question to not to spoil the question with a  long piece of code .

It works perfect when I get the vector as "std::vector". 
Than I can easily initiate my wrapper.

But now there is a legacy code which does not gives the data as a list directly but instead with index :

```
auto count = LegacyObjList->getCount(); 
for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    LegacyObj.getObjByIndex(i);
```

Currently whenever I want to instantiate my  FunctionalIteratableWrapper with this kind of struct which only allow the access with index I am needing to do :

```
std::vector<LegacyObj> tempVec;
auto count = LegacyObjList->getCount(); 
for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    tempVec.push_back(LegacyObj.getObjByIndex(i));

FunctionalIteratableWrapper<LegacyObj> wrapper(temp);
```

I want to avoid this for loop that I am using now for each time creating my wrapper with such object which only allows access with index. What should be best solution?

```
template< typename Value >
class FunctionalIteratableWrapper
{
public:


    /*!
     * \brief A copy ctor like ctor. Which initiates this struct directly from vector of Iteratable.
     * \param list vector of Iteratable
     */
    FunctionalIteratableWrapper( const std::vector<Value>& list  )
    {
        iteratableList = list;
    }

    /*!
     * \brief Default ctor
     */
    FunctionalIteratableWrapper()
    {

    }

    template <typename F>
    FunctionalIteratableWrapper& Filter( F filterFunction, bool isReturnOneElement = false )
    {
        std::vector<Value> newList;
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < iteratableList.size(); i++)
        {
            if ( filterFunction(iteratableList[i]) )
            {
                newList.push_back(iteratableList[i]);
                if ( isReturnOneElement )
                   break;
            }
        }
        iteratableList = newList;
        return *this;
    }

,
    template < typename T, typename F >
    T Find( F filterFunction)
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < iteratableList.size(); i++)
        {
            if ( filterFunction(iteratableList[i]) )
                return Cast<typename T::element_type>(iteratableList[i]);
        }
        return T();
    }

    template <typename T, typename F>
    FunctionalIteratableWrapper& Map( F applyFunction)
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < iteratableList.size(); i++)
        {
            auto castedTerrain = Cast<typename T::element_type>(iteratableList[i]);
            if ( castedTerrain )
                applyFunction(castedTerrain);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    void Append( Value newElement )
    {
        iteratableList.push_back( newElement );
    }



    std::vector<Value> iteratableList;
};
```

Comment: You know your code copies the elements into the wrapper right?  Even if your data was already in a vector?

Comment: Can you please explain, I didnt get your point

Comment: Your `FunctionalIteratableWrapper` does a copy of the entire `std::vector` when you construct it.  It doesn't even permit cheap move semantics (you should google "if you want speed pass by value") if you don't need the source vector.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to handle this is to write an ADL helper function.

First change the constructor:

```
FunctionalIteratableWrapper( std::vector<Value> list  ):
  iterableList(std::move(list))
{
}
```

we now support cheap move-in.

Next, create a namespace:

```
namespace my_utility {
  namespace helper1 {
    template<class T, class A>
    std::vector<T, A> to_vector( std::vector<T, A> in ) {
      return std::move(in);
    }
  }
  namespace helper2 {
    using ::my_utility::helper1::to_vector;
    template<class T>
    auto as_vector( T&& t )
    -> decltype( to_vector( std::forward<T>(t) ) )
    {
      return to_vector( std::forward<T>(t) );
    }
  }
  using ::my_utility::helper2::as_vector;
}
```

now calling `::my_utility::as_vector(x)` does an ADL lookup on `to_vector(x)`.  If it doesn't find it, it tries to deduce `x` as `std::vector<T,A>` and returns a copy.

Now we add a constructor:

```
template<class T,
  class=std::enable_if_t< !std::is_same< std::decay_t<T>, FunctionalIteratableWrapper >::value >
>
FunctionalIteratableWrapper( T&& t ):
  iterableList(::my_utility::as_vector(std::forward<T>(t))
{
}
```

we are almost there!

In the namespace of `LegacyObj`, write this:

```
std::vector<LegacyObj> to_vector( LegacyObjList const* pList ) {
  if (!pList _obj) return {};
  std::vector<LegacyObj> retval;
  int size = pList->getCount();
  retval.reserve(size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    retval.push_back(pList->getObjByIndex(i);
  return retval;
}
```

and it will be magically found by `as_vector` (well, using ADL).

Now a `LegacyObjList const*` can be implicitly converted to your `FunctionalInterableWrapper`.

Code not tested.  You can write `to_vector` first, and manually test it, and get 99% of the way there.

Then do the `::my_utility::as_vector` trick.

Finally, see if you can get the constructor that calls `as_vector` to work.

Each adds value, and can be written separately from the others.